# retrieve nested eloquent relations items

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have 4 models connected with hasMany relations as below:

Brand -> hasMany -> Categories -> hasMany -> subCategories -> hasMany -> products

I want to retrieve the categories that their subcategories have one or more products.

I tried querying relationship existence with `has` and/or `whereHas` but no luck.

Thanx for your advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `has()` dot annotation, should do the trick for you.

```
$categories = Category::has('subCategories.products')->get();
```

Comment: I'm confused why you mention brand, since your question is only related to Categories :/

Comment: I have many brands each with different categories, so I want to list brand1 categories where their subcategories have products

Comment: yes, but you ask directly that you need categories not brands. "I want to retrieve the categories that their subcategories have one or more products."

Comment: I forgot to mention that,,,